# Python multiprocessing on function with return value

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to do principal component analysis on each element of an array . Each element of the array is a matrix. I have 500 such arrays. Each array contains around 50 matrices. Overall it is taking too much time. I want to speed up the process using multiprocessing.

I've written following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def princomp(A):
    A=A.T
    # computing eigenvalues and eigenvectors of covariance matrix

    M = (A-mean(A.T,axis=1)).T # subtract the mean (along columns)

    [latent,coeff] = linalg.eig(cov(M)) # attention:not always sorted

    score = dot(coeff.T,M) # projection of the data in the new space
    top_eigen=[i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(latent), key=lambda x:x[1])]
    #output = random.rand(990,3)
    score = score.real
    output = []
    for a in range(0, 128): 
        output += [score[top_eigen[a]]]
    return numpy.array(output)


def func1(...)
    ...
    ...
    for i in range(0, nframes):      #nframes is around 50
        fc_array[i] = normalize(fc_array[i], axis=1, norm='l1')    #fc_array[i] is a 2D numpy array
        pool = Pool()
        #ans_array[i] = princomp(fc_array[i])    # normal principle component analysis
        result = pool.apply_async(princomp, [fc_array[i]])     # principle component analysis using multiprocessing
        print "Frame No.: ", i
        ans_array[i] = result.get()
        p.close()
        p.join()
    return ans_array
```

It gets stuck inside the for loop of 'func1'. The print statement is not executed. It gets stuck. Am I even doing multiprocessing correctly?
I hope I'll get some help on this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is the `print` statement over-indented?

Comment: Seems to me you're re-creating the pool for each pass in the for loop, that's not good...

Comment: @AlexThornton Sorry. Fixed it

Comment: @mguijarr I tried instantiating it before the for loop or even at the beginning of the script but it still does the same.

Comment: I didn't succeed in replicating it. What's you OS and python version? Anyway, you probably want just to use `pool.map(func, fc_array)`, and it will take care of the sending the function to different workers and populate the result list (currently, your script blocks for every running of the function).